# Is there no way to decrease line spacing on a UILabel's text?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I'm trying desperately to decrease the line spacing on my label's text but it seems that a value of 0 is the lowest you can go on the lineSpacing property of an NSParagraphStyle. Here is my code:

```
let attributedProductName = NSMutableAttributedString(string: product.name!, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: PRODUCT_TITLE_FONT as Any])
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0
attributedProductName.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedProductName.length))
let size = attributedProductName.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: imageWidth - TITLE_LABEL_RIGHT_PADDING, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
titleLabelHeightConstraint.constant = ceil(size.height)
titleLabel?.attributedText = attributedProductName
```